# Difference in how R reads in data when running on OSX vs windows?

Tags: r, macos, csv, encoding

I used `read.csv` to read data into R on my windows machine (windows 7, R version 3.1.1, using R studio Version 0.98.978) and I have no problems.

when I do the same on my Macbook Air (yosemite, R version 3.1.2, same version R studio) I get:

```
Error in make.names(col.names, unique =TRUE) :
   invalid multibyte string at '<a0>T/D'
```

In R on my mac using `fileEconding="latin1"` gets the data in, but everything has a foreign E in front.

Alternatively I saved the file from excel as a csv with 'UTF-8' encoding and then specify the same encoding when reading into R but I get a whole other set of errors.

I tried to post image of data in R but I don't have the enough reputation.

Are there some default settings I need to change in Rstudio on my mac?

Comment: It is a good thing you have so little reputation, because an image of your data would be useless. With any amount of reputation, you could add the results of `sessionInfo()` on both machines, and a reproducible bit of data (via `dput`) that is causing the problems or you could find the part of the file that has the bad string and type it in to the question.

Comment: Keep in mind that this most likely isn't an `R` problem but rather a problem with the way the two operating systems are handling your source file.  A "standard" workaround is to open the .csv file in an external editor such as `TextWrangler` and re-saving on the target machine.

Comment: Carl, i used textwrangler to delete the character that was only recognized when i tried to read the csv into my mac.  while i would prefer to know exactly why my windows machine completely ignored the character, your solution worked. many thanks